# Display all user info from each uid (email, name, etc.) and display in recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How could I get the `firstName` and `lastName` from the firebase database for each user and display it on a recycler view?

Thus, the result would be recycler view items each containing the `firstName` and `lastName` for each user.

This is my current Firebase recyclerviewadapter provided by FirebaseUI:

```
public void recyclerVIewAdapter(View view) {
    Firebase myFirebase = new Firebase("https://mystacks.firebaseio.com/");
    AuthData authdata = myFirebase.getAuth();

    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://mystacks.firebaseio.com/").child("users");

    final RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.findPeopleRV);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<People, findPeopleViewHolder>(People.class, R.layout.recyclerviewlayout, findPeopleViewHolder.class, ref) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(findPeopleViewHolder ViewHolder,People people, int position) {

            ViewHolder.fname.setText(people.getFirstName());
            ViewHolder.lname.setText(people.getLastName());
        }
    };
    recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}


   public static class Users {
    @JsonProperty("personalProfile")
    String personalProfile;

    public String getPersonalProfile() {
        return personalProfile;
    }

    public void setPersonalProfile(People people) {
        personalProfile = people.getFirstName();
        personalProfile = people.getLastName();
    }

    public Users(){
    }
}



public static class People  {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    @JsonCreator
    public People(@JsonProperty("firstName") String firstName, @JsonProperty("lastName") String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public People(){

    }
}
```

**ERROR CODE:**

```
 Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
                                                                                at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3ce9dfee; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Comment: At first glance the code looks good. What's the problem you're having with it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've updated my code and added an error log. I think that my problem is that im not properly deserializing the JSON.

Comment: Ah, I see. I hadn't noticed the nested `personalProfile`. Why don't you simply nest a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're nesting a `personalProfile` property, as it seems useless overhead. Keep in mind that you cannot load partial nodes with Firebase; a node is always either completely loaded or not loaded at all.

But given this structure, you can deserialize it with:

```
public static class User {
    PersonalProfile personalProfile;

    public PersonalProfile getPersonalProfile() {
        return personalProfile;
    }

    public void setPersonalProfile(PersonalProfile profile) {
        personalProfile = profile;
    }
}
public static class PersonalProfile  {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

I highly recommend keeping your POJOs the same as your JSON structure. While you can do many types of mapping with Jackson, it will just make your code harder to maintain. A simple mapping, like the one I have above, makes it less likely that you make mistakes and is easier for others to pick up.